# VB .NET vs. VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I just want to know if VB.NET and VB 2010 are the same.

I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 15):

VB 2010 is the latest version of VB.Net. Microsoft dropped the ".Net" part of VB with the VB 2005 release.

Wikipedia has all you need to know about VB.net: [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)

Answer (score 11):

VB.NET is any version of Visal Basic since version 7, where the language moved to the .NET platform and became object oriented.

2010 isn't a version of the VB language, it's sometimes used to describe the version that comes with Visual Studio 2010, which is VB version 10.

Comment: +1 So accurate it's almost painful ;) "2010 isn't a version of VB..."

Answer (score 8):

As specified on the [wiki page for VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VB.NET) VB 2010, or VB 10.0 is a new version of the language commonly refered to as VB.NET.

Comment: in short they are not the same?

Comment: VB.NET is the name of the language, and VB 2010 is a specific version of that langugage (think Toyota Corolla vs. a E140 Toyota Corolla)

Answer (score 3):

as the time changed visual basic became more advanced. Before it used a p code compiler. but all the versions after  vb 6.0 IDE it stopped using msvb60.dll and shifted to .NET framework which is now called VB.NET. But Microsoft removed the .NET after VB 2005 final release. Also it used a VBC.exe which is the new Visual Basic compiler. There was a lot of criticiscm after this because it was not compatible with Win 98 and previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Basic .NET (VB.NET) implemented on the .NET Framework. Microsoft launched VB.NET in 2002 as the successor to its original Visual Basic language. Although ".NET" portion dropped in 2005,"Visual Basic .NET" to refer to all Visual Basic languages releases since 2002.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Visual Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) and [Visual Basic .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). Visual Basic .NET runs on the [.NET framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) and the former does **not**.

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes, Vb 10 is just the newer version

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are the same, but VB.Net runs with .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are the same. Bassicaly VB 2010 is using .NET framework

Answer (score 1):

Vb.net is the same as VB 2017. In your case it's 2010. Just more features

Answer (score 0):

VB 2010  , because nobody is needed to know .net when they know vb 
but in vb.net you also have to learn .net, 
This version is also the latest
you can also have vb2010 express for free here 
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express
                              (OR) 
get the paid version like pro edition here  (trial only)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2890

Answer (score 0):

`VB.NET` is the language that you can use on the `.NET framework`. Before .NET framework evolved, Microsoft had a separate product called `Visual Basic`, and in 2002 when Microsoft came with .NET framework then they discontinued Visual Basic as independent product, and combined it in the .NET framework.

Basically .NET framework supports 50+ languages (Visual Basic is one of them, and C# is another commonly known language) which you can use to develop variety of applications. Over the years, Microsoft improved .NET framework, so thus the VB language to make it more smart.

The `VB 2010` that you are asking is the Visual Basic language that came with the `Visual Studio 2010`.

Answer (score 0):

VB 2010 is a part of the VB  .NET family. VB.NET uses the .NET language runtime, while VB6 and previous VB does not. VB .NET is object-oriented, and the classic VB is event-driven.